# Cosine Similarity Influence

Tags: python, statistics, cosine-similarity

I'm calculating cosine similarity to understand some yearly trends, and I was curious if there is a way to see which values are most contributing to the similarity?

Is there an influence calculation or method used for lists of words (I think this would be the most similar application) that could say, which words in the list most contribute to the similarity score?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values that contribute to the cosine similarity the most are those which produce the largest (absolute) value when multiplied together.

```
u = [0, 1, 0, 1]
v = [2, 3, 2, 5]

indices = list(range(len(u)))
most_contributing = max(indices, key=lambda i: abs(u[i] * v[i]))
```

Comment: Are you sure this is correct? Isn't the issue that since you are dividing by the norm; large values which may be zero in the other array will reduce the effect of other values within that array.

Comment: @AlexisDrakopoulos Yes, those 'large values' will reduce the effect of other values within that array, but universally, "fairly". There is no value which would be impacted more or less severely than another.